# Does the GitHub Bamboo Service support Bamboo Cloud?

Tags: github, bamboo

Despite receiving a `Last delivery was successful.` the Bamboo Cloud Build Plan is not firing.

I am using:

- *Base url* `devopsgroup-io.atlassian.net`
- *Base key* `DRM-DT`
- *Username* `********`
- *Password* `********`
- *Active* `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the Base url needs to be exactly this format `https://devopsgroup-io.atlassian.net/builds/`. Unfortunately this is not validated when you add the GitHub Bamboo Service.